# Twilio: pro-actively initiate daily, pre-scheduled conference calls?

Tags: twilio, voip, telephony

Scenario is this (I think #2 below is the key question/unknown):

1. User1 & User2 have provided a mutual daily scheduled time (and their phone numbers of course) for when they want to initiate a phone call between each other.
2. Twilio calls User1 & User2 to initiate the daily conference call each day at the designated time
3. Conference call is initiated once both parties pick up.
4. Conference call ends after either hangs up.
5. FYI: conference call is only a maximum of 5 minutes.

Thanks!

Comment: This is very well possible as well as simple. Please take a look into their APIs, you'd have something like a cron or service verifying if new conferences would need to be started, if it finds one, it would create an outbound call (using the REST api) to both parties and, when they pick it up, it would place them on a conference (using the TwiML api). Check out their docs at https://www.twilio.com/docs/api

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer here.

You can definitely build outbound conference calls like this with Twilio.

Building an application like this is a two step process:

First, you need to initiate an outbound call to each participant using the Twilio REST API. This page in our documentation has instructions and code samples for most popular programming languages:

[https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon)

When you make that outbound call, you will need to supply a `url` parameter in your POST request to `https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Calls.`

That URL should point to a part of your application that responds with TwiML, Twilio's markup language. The TwiML you need is pretty simple:

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>Daily call</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

You can find more sample TwiML responses for conference calls in our official docs:

[https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#examples](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=june2015&utm_campaign=stackathon#examples)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Andrew ,I am going through this link for conference call with php https://www.twilio.com/blog/2011/07/easy-conference-calling-twilio.html is this correct flow or should i refer something else. And also conference.xml file means TwiML  is required ? I want conference call with php script. Thanks

Comment: Hi @SaraMichel! That blog post is pretty old, so I might reference this tutorial instead: https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/simple-conference

You will need to generate some TwiML to put your callers into a conference. The twilio-php helper library is the best way to do that:

https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Hi Andrew many thanks for reply , I already referred that link u given but I m not able to understand how to do it in php or in ios.